# How to use regex to allow empty string or a minimum of 6 characters?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some regex that tests against if the string has at least 6 characters. Though I also want it to be true if there is just an empty string also.

Regex:

```
let regexToTestName = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!@#$%^&*()_-]{6,}$/g;
let usedName = ''; //or let usedName = 'atLeast6Char';
let isNameMatch = regexToTestName.test(usedName);
```

As you can see it will work for characters specified of at least 6 in length. But how do I also get a true value if it is an empty string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make your string optional with `?`:

```
/^(\S{6,})?$/
```

```js
var re = /^(\S{6,})?$/

console.log('', re.test(''));
console.log('a', re.test('a'));
console.log('abcde', re.test('abcde'));
console.log('abcdefg', re.test('abcdefg'));
```

Answer (score 1):

The following expression will match the whole string `^ $` for any character `.` if there's `{0}` of them (an empty string) or `|` it will match 6 or more `{6,}` by specifying a range with only the "from" index, a comma, and no "to" index. The "or" expression must be wrapped in a group `( )`.

```js
var re = /^(.{0}|.{6,})$/;

console.log('', re.test(''));
console.log('1', re.test('1'));
console.log('12', re.test('12'));
console.log('123', re.test('123'));
console.log('1234', re.test('1234'));
console.log('12345', re.test('12345'));
console.log('123456', re.test('123456'));
console.log('1234567', re.test('1234567'));
console.log('12345678', re.test('12345678'));
```

Comment: In the process of updating.

Answer (score 0):

Use pipe `|` and grouping to do both.

```
^([/w]{6,0})|([\w]{0,0})$
```